# Oracle Error(6,26): PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle

guys I have no idea why I get this error here is the code. What precision needs int? I assign integer to PATIENT_SSA. I tried also assign this to decimal(19,2) but it didn't work aswell.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIDOWYW 
BEFORE INSERT ON PRESCRIPTION_BILLS 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PATIENTID INT;
PHARMACY_SSA INT;
PATIENT_SSA INT;
PHARMACYID INT;
TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE DOUBLE;
PATIENTINSURANCEPERCENT DOUBLE;
BEGIN
  SELECT PATIENT_ID INTO PATIENTID
  FROM PRESCRIPTIONS
  WHERE PRESCRIPTION_ID = :NEW.PRESCRIPTION_ID;

  SELECT PHARMACY_ID INTO PHARMACYID
  FROM PRESCRIPTIONS
  WHERE PRESCRIPTION_ID = :NEW.PRESCRIPTION_ID;

  SELECT  SSA_ID INTO PATIENT_SSA
  FROM PATIENTS JOIN KIND_OF_INSURANCES USING (INSURANCE_ID)
  WHERE PATIENT_ID=PATIENTID;

  SELECT  SSA_ID INTO PHARMACY_SSA
  FROM CONTRACTS_WITH_PHARMACY
  WHERE SSA_ID=PATIENT_SSA AND PHARMACY_ID = PHARMACYID AND SYSDATE BETWEEN BEGIN_DATE AND END_DATE;

  SELECT SUM(MEDICINE.PRICE) AS SUM1 INTO TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE
  FROM  MEDICINE_ON_PRESCRIPTION JOIN MEDICINE USING (MEDICINE_ID)
  WHERE PRESCRIPTION_ID = :NEW.PRESCRIPTION_ID;

  IF(PHARMACY_SSA)THEN
  SELECT PERCENTAGE.PERCENTAGE_VALUE/100 INTO PATIENTINSURANCEPERCENT 
  FROM (PATIENTS JOIN KIND_OF_INSURANCES USING (INSURANCE_ID)) JOIN PERCENTAGE USING (PERCENTAGE_ID)
  WHERE PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID = PATIENT_ID; 
  :NEW.TO_PAY_BY_PATIENT:= TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE * PATIENTINSURANCEPERCENT;
  :NEW.TO_PAY_BY_SSA := TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE - :NEW.TO_PAY_BY_PATIENT;
  ELSE
  :NEW.TO_PAY_BY_PATIENT:= TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE;
  :NEW.TO_PAY_BY_SSA :=0;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the full error stack and message? Is this part of a script or multiple statements you're running together? Line 6 isn't the PATIENT_SSA, the PL/SQL error would count lines from the DECLARE; but the actual line 6, TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE, looks OK too. Though I'd use number with precision/scale rather than double. So it's probably not coming from this bit of code...

Comment: Change from double to numbers helped thanks!

Comment: I avoid ANSI types so much I'd forgotten that just `double` is not actually OK... following my own advice and looking at the docs helped *8-) Still, it would help if you include the full error message/stack in future.

Comment: Binary floating point data types prove the existence of God by negation, as they are clearly the work of the devil. :-) (Example: `printf("%.17f\n", 0.1 + 0.31);` results in "0.41000000000000003". Wait - 0.1 + 0.31 != 0.41?!? What?! Whoa!!!) DO NOT EVER use a binary floating point type to store monetary values - unless you really *like* talking to auditors, that is. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are a little odd as the `CREATE TRIGGER` is SQL, but the body is PL/SQL. When you get a PL/SQL error like this, the line number is only within the PL/SQL part, so you have to start counting from the `DECLARE`. That makes line six your `TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE` declaration.

As shown [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213), Oracles does support the ANSI types listed there, but you need the keyword PRECISION:

> The DOUBLE PRECISION data type is a floating-point number with binary precision 126.

So you would need to use:

```
TOTAL_FOR_MEDICINE DOUBLE PRECISION;
```

You should consider the values you want though, and maybe use a NUMBER data type instead, specifying the appropriate precsiion and scale, to avoid rounding errors from float types.

Answer (score 0):

In your case its better to define it same way as it was defined in table:

```
DECLARE    
PATIENTID PRESCRIPTIONS.PATIENT_ID%TYPE;
```

And so on.
In most cases its better to use `NUMBER` data type for column and for variables as well.